# Spring MVC can not find Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I am new to Spring MVC. I went through the basic and everything works fine. Then when I try to hook up Spring MVC to my current project, the Controller did not get called.

Here is my servlet-context.xml

```
<annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory--> 
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.nelnet.quikstage.webapp.controller" />
```

And here is my Controller

```
package net.nelnet.quikstage.webapp.controller;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome! you are under Home Section "+ locale.toString());

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        return "/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
    }
}
```

I separate my project into One parent and two sub-projects. I was trying to implement Spring MVC into one of the sub-projects. I am not sure weather the project structure cause the problem

Comment: In your spring config xml, do you have a `mvc` prefix declared, like `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`.

Comment: Can you describe your project structure in more detail?

Comment: Are there any errors printed out on server startup?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. my spring config file is fine and no error on server startup. Actually I found the problem. By default, `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`, it doesn't like resource to be empty when there is `"**"` either delete the '**' or put something under the folder will solve the problem